# How to change install destination folder permisions in InnoSetup?

Tags: installation, inno-setup

Say we install into Programm Files into folder PF/MyCoolApp/. We require Admin privileges for installation. How to make it possible for our application when started from user be capable to write into installation folder (download files, rewrite files, start downloaded applications)?

Answer (score 1):

Do you use

```
[Setup] 
PrivilegesRequired=admin
```

? If yes then user must enter admin credentials (UAC dialog is shown) and then he has automatically rigths to write to installation folder.

If he does not have these rights he cannot write to these (protected) folders but he may use Local app folder, Temp folder and many others designed for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

While this is not impossible, it is extremely anti-recommended practice (eg. if you do it, you fail Windows Logo certification).

If you want to provide upgrade functionality, the correct way to do it is to have your application download an installer (such as the Inno installer used to install the application in the first place, or a smaller "patch-style" updater) into a folder that you do have rights to (such as the user's temporary folder), and then execute that, letting it elevate to admin permissions and install as normal.

Or simply detect when an upgrade is ready and link the user to the download page for your application so that they can download the update themselves.